# Online measurement of capacitance of open-load AC cable

Tags: capacitance

I would like to detect whether a three-conductor (L1, N, GND) AC cable's length has been increased – for example, when a connector with attached cable is inserted into a standard/unmodified connector. The challenge is detecting this condition with or without a load (closed or open circuit). When the cable is inserted into the connector, 120V @ 60Hz AC will be present on the cable's line and neutral wires.

Any creative thoughts on how I could achieve something like this? I suspect that the only to way to do is measure changes in the cable's capacitance, but I'm not sure how I would do this "online" – in other words, during both high (closed circuit) and low (open circuit) current conditions.

Comment: Seems unlikely that this cable is isolated from a power source? (and its wiring). That power source, and network of connecting wires, with on/off switches and varying loads would make this a much more difficult project.

Comment: Just perhaps applying "reflectometry" ... What kind of "load" ?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to detect whether a three-conductor (L1, N, GND) AC cable's length has been increased ...

You can make this measurement through the "reflectometry" test (Tdl = 100 ns, 150 ns, 200 ns).
While "superposing" power at 50 Hz and this circuit.

Like this one ... Measuring the "frequencies" of the "dips" and "reporting" these to the "length" ...

[image]

And here is the realized circuit.

[image]